# c# - How should i create byte from bits?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I'm developing app that will send data over `RTP`, but I almost never worked with bytes. Right now I'm trying to use `BitArray`:

```
byte[] toSend = new byte[12];
BitArray b = new BitArray(new int[] { 2 });
b.CopyTo(toSend, 0);
```

but it works with `Int32`, so 2 is represented like `0100..0`, and that's not what I need. I have 2 questions here:

1. How should i combine `2|1|1|4` bits into one byte? I think there should be something that looks like:

   ```
   int version = 2;//2 bits
   int padding = 0;//1 bit
   int extension = 0;//1 bit
   int ccrc = 0;//4 bits

   byte[] toSend = new byte[1]{version+padding+extension+ccrc};
   ```
2. For some headers there are 16 bits reserved, so i need something
   like this: `0000000000000000(16)`, but i don't know how to create this kind of variable, and how to write 16 bits into two bytes.

Comment: Dont forget to check for endianness/ add a exception if the system has the wrong endianess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a byte from bits.

Why not use a a function that takes a byte, the bit value and the position to place the bit as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)?

Comment: I think it answers my first question. But how can i store 16bit and 32bit values? Simple Int16 or Int32?

Comment: you can either create a byte array ( that way it wouldnt matter the int size) or let the function return a long long and cast the result to what ever you need

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the second point. How to create a variable that holds up 16 bits ( 2 bytes ) containing only `0`'s :

```
char _16bitsOfZero = '\0'; // this will have the default value of NULL character
// which basically is 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Going further to creating one byte value from your 4 integers :

```
int version = 2; // 2 bits which will be shifted to the most left
int padding = 0; // 1 bit which will be shifted to the most left but just before version
int extension = 0; // 1 bit which will be shifted to right before padding
int ccrc = 0; // 4 bits that ... wont be shifted.

// first of all this all is going to be one byte ( 8 bits )
// 00 0 0 0000 <- beginning value
byte b = 0;
// now we want to shift our ccrc to be in the back
// 00 0 0 ccrc <- like this
// to put this value there we need to shift this 
b = (byte)ccrc;
// now we want to shift extension right after ccrc value
// remembering that ccrc is 4 bits wide :
b |= (extension << 4);
// now do the same with padding :
b |= (padding << 5); // 4 because previous value was 1 bit wide
// now the same with version :
b |= (version << 6);
// output from this should be :
// 10 0 0 0000
// which is 128
```

To check if it really is `128` go [here](http://rextester.com/PZYPI97006)

```
// to be more precise :
// assume ccrc = 15 ( 0000 1111 )
// and b = 0 ( 0000 0000 )
// now use shift :
b |=
    (ccrc << 1) // will produce the output of ( 0001 1110 )
```